# Expected argument of type "Boolean", "string" given on Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, boolean

I'm currently trying to create a form with fields filled with data from my database by default.

I use:

```
$infos = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository('TestMyBundle:My')
              ->find($id);
$form = $this->createForm(new TestType(), $infos);`
```

But i always get this error message: Expected argument of type "Boolean", "string" given on Symfony2. the second parameter $infos is probably the reason of this message but it's the way to add some defaults values in a form field with Symfony2.

Can anyone help me please ?

Here is the code of my TestType.php class:

```
class   TestType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');

    $builder->add('description');

    $builder->add('access', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'private access: ',
    'required'  => false,));

    $builder->add('visibility', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'private group: ',
    'required'  => false,));

    $builder->add('invitation', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'ask: ',
    'required'  => false));

    $builder->add('wall', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'wall: ',
    'required'  => false,));
}
```

Comment: I don't think your error comes from this piece of code.
Where does your exception come from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the exception come from: vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/BooleanToStringTransformer.php at line 41

Comment: Need more code to help you... What in your TestType class ?

Comment: @Katcha it's because one of the configured fields tries to transform the data into a boolean but it's a string...
Maybe you choosed the wront type for your field.

Comment: I just build my form on this class to reuse it ...

Comment: Thx Herzult i'm gonna to check that, thanks for your help !

Comment: Yeah thanks Herzult you'r right !!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error after I reloaded my form with a checked value that was already persisted.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_recibido", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $isRecibido=null;
```

Then I *changed* it to

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_recibido", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $isRecibido=null;
```

The field in database is integer but doctrine understand and convert it to boolean to the form and an Integer when It goes to the database.

Now everything started to work smooth and nice